# CouchDB view distinct/unique value from two fields

Tags: couchdb, distinct

```
"myview": {
           "map": "function(doc) {if(doc.type == 'call') {emit([doc.from_user, doc.to_user], doc.type);} }",
           "reduce": "function (key, values) {return values;}"
       }
```

POST request with group = true

```
{
"keys":[["123456"], ["123456"]]
}
```

How can I get unique doc based on value exists in either in `from_user` or `to_user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emit the values of `doc.from_user` and `doc.to_user` as single keys.

e.g.

`emit(doc.from_user, doc.type);`

`emit(doc.to_user, doc.type);`

Every row of the view result includes the `doc._id` and  you can also get the doc in the view result by using the query param `include_docs=true`.

Finally you request your view with the query param `?key="your_value"` and you will get every row with that value as key.

---

If you want to know whether the value is from `doc.from_user` or `doc.to_user` just emit that information as part of the value **or** build as multi key like

`emit([doc.from_user, 'from_user'], doc.type);`

`emit([doc.to_user, 'to_user'], doc.type);`

Then you can request

`?startkey=["your_value","from_user"]&endkey=["your_value","to_user"]`

Comment: If i do like 

`emit(doc.from_user, doc.to_user);`
`emit(doc.to_user, doc.type);`

it return same value multiple time if exists in many docs... reduce seems not helping

Comment: The reduce function you have provided in your initial question does not reduce. You have to manipulate the `values` array and return it finally. Maybe thats the second step before the first (in the meaning of better understanding) - try out the built-in reduce function `_count`  in Futon's view UI and play a little with the reduce configuration parameter at the interface.